# Сравнение переменных ==

Tags: java

```
String q = "a";
String l = "a";
String w = q + "b";
String e = "ab";

System.out.println(q == l); //true 
System.out.println(w == e); //false
System.out.println(w.getBytes().length); // 2
System.out.println(e.getBytes().length); // 2
```

Почему false? Как происходит сравнение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`==` сравнивает ссылки, а не переменные (за исключением примитивных типов).

`"a"` - это константа. Соответственно переменные `q` и `l` ссылаются на одну и ту же константу.

А выражение `w = q + "b"` пораждает новую строку, и ссылка на нее отличается от ссылки на строку `"ab"`, на которую ссылается переменная `e`.

Answer (score 3):

С помощью оператора сравнения == сравниваются не объекты, а ссылки на них.

```
String q = "a";
String l = new String("a");
String qa = q;

q == l //false
q == qa //true, одна и та же ссылка
q.equals(l) //true, сравнились объекты-строки, посимвольно.
```

Правильно сравнивать строки с помощью метода `equals`.

http://www.quizful.net/interview/java/equals-equality-difference
Вот маленькая статья

Comment: > http://www.quizful.net/interview/java/equals-equality-difference Вот маленькая статья

ТС лучше бы не статью, а учебник по Java прочитать.

Comment: Nofate, если бы вопрос состоял в том, что почитать, тогда б так и ответили